# Unable to execute java program from crontab job of other user

Tags: java, linux, shell

I am unable to run a crontab job , under a different user.(For e.g sudo -u someuser crontab -e)
It runs absolutely fine under my user profile.
I know what is the issue, but cannot find the resolution for it.
The issue is , when i configure this crontab job for other user, crontab is not able to find java ,as a result even simple java -version is not working.

Below is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/home/VishalS/bin

echo "JAVA_HOME is: " $JAVA_HOME >>  log.out
echo "PATH is: " $PATH >>  log.out

which java >> log.out

/usr/bin/java -version >> log.out
/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/java -version >> log.out
```

---

output of above script :

```
JAVA_HOME is:  /usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31
PATH is:  /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/home/VishalS/bin
/usr/bin/java
```

so obviously, the below lines did not work.

```
/usr/bin/java -version >> log.out
/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/java -version >> log.out
```

Could somebody please help me here? I do not understand why even after setting jdk path crontab does not executes java -version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your helpful comments.
However the actual fix which worked in my-case , was mix of steps as mentioned below :-
1. Setup Sun JDK path under root's user profile.(earlier open jdk was setup)
2. Gave permission to logs folder where logs were being written.(earlier the permission were not correctly set)
3. Tweaked my cronjob(i think there was an extra space there)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the paths in the other users crontab directly.  See 'man 5 crontab'.

Comment: I did like this  :JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31
54 08  * * * path/to/myscript.sh   . It still does not work

Answer (score 0):

The only that comes to my mind is that, the `java` command might not have the Executable permission to the user you are trying to execute it from.

So use `chmod` to give necessary permissions to execute.

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried doing "chmod 755 java.sh" but got permission denied.(This is a production machine , so i am taking help of sysadmin here.)

Answer (score 0):

Crontab(5) runs without ENV, so you need to source an environment (you are building the JAVA_HOME and PATH, but crontab gives you (almost) nothing.  notice that the output of "which java" did not appear in your log file.

- build an environment script you can source for your crontab script(s), ". path/to/env.sh"
- Put full paths on all programs executed in shell scripts etc.  You cannot rely upon environment in cron
- run "which which", did you get /usr/bin/which?  then put that in your script.
- we often omit paths from scripts for convenience, but give paths in scripts run from crontab
- does the java run when logged in as the other user?

Comment: Thanks Chuck for your valuable inputs.